# Where is Docker storing the images?

Tags: docker

I use Docker for a PHP project.. and he is grabbing my space every time I do a new build is seams that he is duplicate the images.

I tried to delete the images manual in the terminal with docker rm ... but the hdd space is already in use.

I can't finde the docker location on my osx.

Can you tell my where are all the files are stored and how can I delete it?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in "[How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309)", make sure you don"t keep dangling images after each `docker build` (intermediate images no longer used by your current image because of a changing Dockerfile):

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

[While the images are stored in `/var/lib/docker/{driver-name}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25978888/6309) (inside the boot2docker or docker-machine VM used on a Mac mac), you wouldn't remove images manually from that path.

Answer (score 1):

To remove docker images, you should follow the steps bellow:

- List docker images: `docker images`
- Choose Image Ids you need to remove and type command: `docker rmi IMAGE_ID`. Make note that you have to stop the image before remove it