# no space left on device while installing a tar using docker

Tags: docker

I was installing a docker based tar file on my Windows7-64bit system using `Docker` `quickstart` Terminal.

```
docker load -i some_docker_image.tar
```

The command did some processing silently and flash an output:

```
 Error response from daemon: Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output:
 write /usr/include/c++/4.4.4/gnu/java/net/protocol/http/Handler.h: no space left on device
```

How to clean the partially installed tar package to cleanup hard-disk space that is unnecessarily occupied?

Answer (score 11):

Start by [cleaning dangling images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309):

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

First, make sure all your containers are stopped and removed: check the state with a `docker ps -a`.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I tried that option earlier (except I didnot stop and removed) too but still my memory is too low. docker ps -a returns nothing.

Comment: @amp what docker machine version are you using?

Comment: I am running Windows based Docker quickstart terminal on Win7-64bit and with version: Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

Comment: @amp Then simply try an create a new machine: `docker-machine create newmachine && docker-machine ssh newmachine`: see if, in `newmachine`, you can do a `docker pull` successfully.

Comment: Thanks VonC. But I must need ample space to try those commands. Also I don't want to pull as my image is already in tar format. So priority is to clean space which may have occupied by dangled images from that tar. Current C drive status is like: 2.18 GB free out-of 99.9 GB.

Comment: @amp no need to pull then. Try docker load in that new machine.