# Docker how to clean partial failed downloads for images?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker toolbox in OS X. When I run `docker-compose pull` and the network cuts out, the download does not resume after I fix the issue. Is there a way to purge or invalidate partial downloads for docker images?

Answer (score 6):

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381417/docker-how-to-clean-partial-failed-downloads-for-images/34381532#comment105723136_34381532), incomplete images would not be present anyway.

Since [PR 18353](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/18353) and [docs-v1.11.2-2016-06-10](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/ac453a310bac6bdd7cd9d780a63d4168064570d1), the next pull would reload missing/incommplete layers and build the complete image.

- For purging images (dangling or not used): [`docker image prune -a`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)
- For purging containers: [`docker container prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)

[See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309).

Comment: I've got the same problem. `docker images -f "dangling=true" -q` doesn't print any images, so I assume there are no dangling images.

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any indeed.

Comment: Not a proper answer as incomplete downloads do not become images

Comment: @joshfindit Thank you for the feedback, and good point: I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VonC Excellent. Would you also mind putting in the documentation or command for purging or invalidating partial downloads (if it exists)? In my case, for example, I did a `run` which prompted a download of 16 (!) layers. 12 completed and the drive ran out of space downloading the other 4. Afterwards the space was not cleared and there's no intuitive (or that I could find: documented) way to clear that space when I have no intention of using that container in future.

Comment: @joshfindit Sure. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the Docker cache.  Incomplete docker builds can remain partially cached, and cause rebuild to fail.  Use the prune command to clear the build cache.

`docker buildx prune`