# Jenkins build an image for Docker?

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm a beginner with Jenkins CI integration with Docker.
My virtual machine tcp://192.168.99.100:2376

I created an image "personluz" with my SVN source code and the configuration like this image

[image config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKspS.png)
[image: config]

But the result is:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBOU.png)
[image: error message]

> FATAL: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory

Could anyone have some idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, the tag highlighted in the first picture is *not* the one for the `personluz` image (it is one of a [dangling image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309))

The tag for `personluz` is `b7782bf4cf30`.

Second, a  `Cannot run program "docker": error=2` means that, in the context of the Jenkins slave executing the job, docker is not found in the Jenkins user `$PATH`. Make sure it is properly installed for that Jenkins user.

Comment: Many thanks about your response. For the second problem, How should I do for resolve the it?

Comment: @DucHoang It depends on your version of Jenkins, and on where the job is executing (on which slave, with which OS). Do you have https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin installed?

Comment: Yes, I just imported it after your last comment. What should I do next? I'm the beginner of this, very thank u for your big instruction. :)

Comment: @DucHoang I don't have much experience with it yet, so the doc associated with that plugin should enable you to make some tests.

Comment: After import this plugin and rebuild again, the problem still happens. :(

Comment: @DucHoang Hence the need to read the doc and make some tests.

Comment: Ah, Okay, I also do some research ... :), If you get some informations about it, please share with this topic. :)