# run docker build in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using [CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Custom+Build+Environment+Plugin) jenkins plugin to run my jobs inside container.

The problem is that I cannot build image. I am receiving this error:

```
Build Docker image from ./Dockerfile ...
$ docker build --file /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Frontend/Dockerfile /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Frontend
FATAL: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

When I run `which docker` it returns `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

It seems that jenkins cannot access docker.

I am using MacOS X

Similar question:
[Jenkins build an image for Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848745/jenkins-build-an-image-for-docker)

Comment: Can you try `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker` ? the problem is that the user jenkins does not have the privilege to run docker.

Comment: @hichamx It didn't help. If there would be privilege problem then it wouldn't show directory not found error or am I wrong?

Comment: the `which docker` command, did you run it as the user named "jenkins" created by jenkins?

Comment: yes, both root and jenkins and it returns same path.

Comment: can you try this command `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins` and the run the jenkins job again

Comment: I cannot run this command because I am using OS X. `sudo: usermod: command not found`

Comment: I don't know about macOS but the idea is to add the user jenkins to the group docker, if there is no group called docker you have to create one.

Comment: As an alternative to adding jenkins to the docker group, you can try to run the command as `sudo docker build ...` assuming jenkins user has sudo rights. However, be warned, jenkins has problems with sudo, at least on linux

Comment: By which user did you run Jenkins job?

Comment: @Yuankun Does it matter? Every jenkins build jobs is executing `jenkins` user, right? On my laptop I am logged as user with sudo privileges.

Comment: @Joozty there is a comment in the following question, which seems to answer you question (the whole question remains unanswered, therefore not marking as duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391391/do-we-have-docker-group-on-mac  And another hint here https://serverfault.com/questions/639459/why-might-the-jenkins-user-not-have-permission-to-access-the-docker-unix-socket/659043#659043

Comment: Thank you @OlegSklyar but changing permission didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You need understand if it is `docker` command itself causing the issue or arguments to it. Try setting up a basic jenkins job that doesn't run a custom build but instead deploys something from the hub, aka `docker run hello-world`. Then you will know if the problem is with docker or docker build

Comment: here is a workaround here https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/799

Comment: @hichamx Yes, that was first what I tried before I ask this question. Unfortunelly it didn't help.

Comment: Any joy getting this resolved?