# How to remove all tags for a docker repository locally?

Tags: bash, docker

I want to remove all tags on a given docker repository locally.  For example, if I had two tags on a repo called "my_image:latest" and "my_image:sometag" I would want to remove both of those tags.  However, I do not want to remove "another_image:latest".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line mostly:

```
docker images | grep "$DOCKER_REPO" | awk '{system("docker rmi " "'"$DOCKER_REPO:"'" $2)}'
```

Remember you can't remove images that are being used unless you use the -f option.

Answer (score 7):

To list the images you want to remove:

```
$ docker images --filter='reference=my_image' --format='{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}'
```

To delete them as well, combine with `docker rmi`:

```
$ docker images --filter='reference=my_image' --format='{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | xargs docker rmi
```

Comment: Use `xargs -r` to avoid failing when there is no image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following shell function:

```
dockercleanrepo(){
    docker images --no-trunc --format '{{.ID}} {{.Repository}}' \
    | grep "$@" | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -t docker rmi
}
```

Add it to bashrc, zshrc and use it simply with:

```
dockercleanrepo <your-repoitory>
```

Also related to this, check the answers for the question [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if something changed since @jcmack posted that answer or if google container registry is special but it didn't work as is; I adapted it:

```
docker images | grep "gcr.io/project-id" | awk '{system("docker rmi " $1 ":" $2)}'
```