# Error while cleaning images from docker

Tags: docker

When I run

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

from the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723111/5931467) question I sometimes get

```
docker: "rmi" requires a minimum of 1 argument.
```

am I doing something wrong? How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with that answer is that it runs `docker rmi` even though there might not be any images to delete (that is when the output from `docker images --filter....` is empty), and that is when you get the error.

@rubicks solution to that question doesn't do a much better job, but points to a usable alternative:

```
docker images --no-trunc --all --quiet --filter="dangling=true" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

the `--no-run-if-empty` argument to `xargs` does what it says and prevents that error from happening, even if you run it and you have nothing to clean.

I have the following aliases, because the above is a bit too much to type every time I want to use it (the first is for removing unused containers):

```
alias drrm='docker ps --no-trunc --all --quiet --filter="status=exited" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm'
alias drrmi='docker images --no-trunc --all --quiet --filter="dangling=true" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi'
```

Comment: That solution does not work on OS X, as xargs does not support the --no-run-if-empty flag.