# Cannot stop container with docker on windows

Tags: docker

I have installed docker toolbox for windows and run hello-world.

I now want to stop it with

```
docker stop hello-world
```

But this generate an error :

> failed to stop container (hello-world) no such container

When I do docker images hello-world is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I do `docker images` hello-world is there

But when you do a `docker ps -a`, do you see a *container* hello-workd running? (or at all?)

[`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) stops a running container, not an image.

[`hello-world` is an image](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/) which, when executed as a container, [prints hello-world](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/22ecfe456f254d5babe6e413bed2de77cfaba047/Dockerfile#L3) and immediately exit. There is nothing to stop at this point.

Comment: I can see hello-world with docker ps -a but status is exited. I have another one jenkins which is up I cannot stop either. How do I stop that one it seems to have a container name only an id ?

Comment: @user310291 For the one existed, I would advice a `drmae` (an alias that I use to remove all exited containers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309: it is short for "docker remove all exited containers")

Comment: "How do I stop that one it seems to have a container name only an id?" You can use its id to stop it (or stop and remove with `docker rm -f`)