# How to delete unused docker images in swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have a system where user may install some docker containers. We dont have a limit on what he can install. After some time, we need to clean up - delete all the images that are not in used in the swarm.

What would be the solution for that using docker remote API?

Our idea is to have background image-garbage-collector thread that:

- lists all the images
- try to delete some
- if it fails, just ignore

Would this make sense? Would this affect swarm somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Cleaner way to list and (try to) remove all images

The command `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` would do the same as the answer by @tpbowden but in a cleaner way. The `-q|--quiet` only list the images ID.

#### It may delete frequently used images (not running at the cleaning date)

If you do this, when the user will try to `swarm run deleted-image` it will:

1. Either pull the image (**< insert network consumption warning here />**)
2. Either just block as the pull action is not automatic in swarm if I remember it right (**< insert frequent support request warning here about misunderstood Swarm behavior />**).

#### "dangling=true" filter:

A useful option is the `--filter "dangling=true"`. Executing `swarm images -q --filter "dangling=true"` will display not-currently-running images.

---

#### Though challenge

You issue reminds me the memory management in a computer. Your real issue is:

> How to remove image that won't be used in the future?

Which is really hard and really depends on your policy. If your policy is *old images are to be deleted* the command that could help is: `docker images --format='{{.CreatedSince}}:{{ .ID}}'`. But then the hack starts... You may need to `grep "months"` and then `cut -d ':' -f 2`.

The whole command would result as:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --format='{{.CreatedSince}}:{{ .ID}}' G months | cut -d ':' -f 2)
```

Note that this command will need to be run on every Swarm agent as well as the Swarm manager, not **only** the Swarm manager.

#### Swarm and registry

Be aware than a `swarm pull image:tag` **will not** pull the image on Swarm agents! Each Swarm agent must pull the image itself. Thus deleting still used images will result in network load.

I hope this answer helps. At this time there is no mean to query "*image not used since a month*" AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is '[prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)'

```
$ docker image prune --filter until=72h --force --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker images | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

This will list all images, strip the top line with column headings, grab the 3rd column (image ID hash) and then attempt to remove them all. Docker will prevent you from removing any images that are currently used by running containers.

If you want to do this in a slightly less 'hacky' way, you could use Docker's API to get images which aren't being used and delete them that way.

Comment: thanx! do you have insights if this affects much running of the swarm?

Comment: Not sure how this might affect the swarm - you might end up with images deleted from some nodes but not all of them. It won't have a noticable overhead on performance if thats what you mean - it's just deleting files from disk.