# Docker Swarm: How to remove stopped containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

i am currently learning docker and have set up a swarm with one manager and one cluster.

i run a stack with 2 replicas..everything is fine. when a container fails to run swarm will stop it and recreate it. thats awesome but the stopped containers wont get removed. is there a way to remove the stopped / unused containers automatically ?

[Docker Swarm unused containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6fV6.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a option `--task-history-limit`.

So you can do something like this:

`docker swarm update --task-history-limit=1`

Take a look at the cli docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_update/

Answer (score 1):

Docker swarm doesn't provide a way of removing stopped containers automatically.

You will have to run `docker system prune --all` manually on your node or create a cron-job which does that for your.

see also: [How to delete unused docker images in swarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775109/how-to-delete-unused-docker-images-in-swarm)