# Docker run command is not applied to the image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.119

USER jenkins
ENV HOME /var/jenkins_home

COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins ssh ${HOME}/.ssh/

RUN chmod 700 ${HOME}/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 ${HOME}/.ssh/*
```

The ssh directory has 755/644 on the dir/file on the build machine. However, when I build with

```
docker build -t my/temp .
```

and start the image with an ls command

```
docker run -it --rm my/temp ls -la /var/jenkins_home/.ssh
```

neither of the chmod commands are applied to the image

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May  3 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins 4096 May  3 12:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  391 May  3 11:42 known_hosts
```

During the build I see

```
Step 4/6 : COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins ssh ${HOME}/.ssh/
 ---> 58e0d8242fac
Step 5/6 : RUN chmod 700 ${HOME}/.ssh &&     chmod 600 ${HOME}/.ssh/*
 ---> Running in 0c805d4d4252
Removing intermediate container 0c805d4d4252
 ---> bbfc828ace79
```

It looks like the chmod is discarded. How can I stop this happening?

I'm using latest Docker (Edge) on Mac OSX 
Version 18.05.0-ce-rc1-mac63 (24246); edge 3b5a9a44cd

**EDIT**

With --rm didn't work either (after deleting image and rebuilding) but didn't get remove message

```
docker build -t my/temp --rm=false .

run -it --rm my/temp ls -la /var/jenkins_home/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May  3 15:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins 4096 May  3 15:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  391 May  3 11:42 known_hosts
```

**EDIT 2**

So basically a bug in Docker where a base image with a VOLUME causes chmod to fail and similarly RUN mkdir on the volume failed but COPY did, but left the directory with the wrong permissions. Thanks to [bkconrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933963/bkconrad).

**EDIT 3**

Created fork with a fix here https://github.com/systematicmethods/jenkins-docker
build.sh will build an image locally

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how Docker handles `VOLUME`s for images.

From `docker inspect my/temp`:

```
"Volumes": {
  "/var/jenkins_home": {}
},
```

There's a helpful ticket about this from the moby project:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12779

Basically you'll need to do your `chmod` at run time.

Setting your `HOME` envvar to a non-volume path like `/tmp` shows the expected behavior:

```
$ docker run -it --rm my/temp ls -la /tmp/.ssh
total 8
drwx------ 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May  3 17:31 .
drwxrwxrwt 6 root    root    4096 May  3 17:31 ..
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins    0 May  3 17:24 dummy
```

Comment: The link is very helpful also explains why RUN commands on the same volume don't work. Basically a bug in Docker imho. Spent the best part of a day trying to find work-arounds as I assumed I must have done something wrong as I'm still relatively new to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 5/6 : RUN chmod 700 ${HOME}/.ssh &&     chmod 600 ${HOME}/.ssh/*
 ---> Running in 0c805d4d4252

Removing intermediate container 0c805d4d4252
```

As you can see "intermediate container " is being removed , which is a normal behavior of the docker to keep , if you wanted to keep those use below command.

```
docker build -t my/temp --rm=false .
```

Its also been explained in one of the post

[Why docker build image from docker file will create container when build exit incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808476/why-docker-build-image-from-docker-file-will-create-container-when-build-exit-in)

Comment: Tried that after deleting the image, didn't work, but didn't get removing message

Comment: Changing the permissions of files the ssh directory helps, but doesn't change permissions of .ssh directory, the COPY statement is at fault, doesn't preserve permissions but more bizarrely doesn't allow you to change permissions either.