# Ubuntu 14.04 volume disk full due to docker data

Tags: docker, orientdb

I have been trying to setup a graph database using orientdb. So I tried using volumes by the following command

```
docker run -d -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480     -v config:/orientdb/config     -v database:/orientdb/databases     -v backup:/orientdb/backup     -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypasswdhere     orientdb:latest
```

My prime motive behind using volumes was to store data in database after I kill the container.
But I used this command frequently to start the server.

Now it has hogged my disk space so I guess it creates a new copy each time this command is executed.

Can someone indicate a correct way to use existing volumes to use stored data in docker and to clean up the redundant data recreated by frequent execution of this command?

Comment: there is cleanup command for containers, images and volumes. dont have those in my memory at the moment, but you can easily sesrch, imo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create *named* volumes with [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)

```
$ docker volume create --name hello
$ docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world
```

That way, only one volume in /var/lib/docker/volumes will be used each time you launch that container.
See also "[Mount a shared-storage volume as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume)".

In the meantime, to [remove dangling volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616890/6309):

```
docker volume ls -qf "dangling=true" | xargs docker volume rm
```

Comment: I will like to point out that I never used command like     `docker volume create --name hello` to add the new volume but I am directly using  `docker run -d -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480     -v config:/orientdb/config     -v database:/orientdb/databases     -v backup:/orientdb/backup     -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypasswdhere     orientdb:latest
` to run my database each time is that a problem because I see a lot of alphanumeric volume name except 'config' ,'backup' and database (that I gave) when I run `docker volume ls` command. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Abhimanyu in that case, you would mount a local host folder "config" to :/orientdb/config. It is best to create a named volume and mount that volume.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I still think that creating a named volume would allow you to reuse it no matter how you create or reuse your container. In other words, you initially chose the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you aren't re-using the container, instead you start a new one each time.
After the first run, you can stop and the restart it with docker stop/start commands.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right now I use start and stop to work in the same container till eternity :)