# Docker container keeps restarting

Tags: docker

I was trying rancher.
I used the command:
    sudo docker run -d --restart=always -p 8080:8080 rancher/server
to start run it.
Then I stopped the container and removed it. But if I stop and restart the docker daemon or reboot my laptop, and lookup running containers using docker ps command, it will have rancher server running again. How do I stop/remove it completely and make sure it will not run again.

Comment: I tried to stop and remove all running containers, then stop and restart docker daemon to see if the container would start again. It keep on restarting in a different container id. I am not sure what was happening or if its a bug. I repeated stop remove step many times untill no containers was restarting. Now it seems to have stopped finally

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Note: following [issue 11008](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11008) and [PR 15348](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15348) ([commit fd8b25c](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/fd8b25c802780683cc5776e6d3aaca9536e7370b), docker v1.11.2), you would avoid the issue with:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:8080 rancher/server
```

In your current situation, thanks to [PR 19116](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19116), you can use [`docker update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) to update the restart policy.

```
docker update --restart=unless-stopped <yourContainerID_or_Name>
```

Then stop your container, restart your docker daemon: it won't restart said container.

---

The [OP codefire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3696133/codefire) points to another reason [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715934/docker-container-keeps-restarting/38716397#comment64828556_38716397):

> When I first ran the start rancher server command, I didn't notice that it was being downloaded. So I may have retried that command a couple times.
>
> That must be why the job kept on restarting even after stopping and removing containers that was started as rancher server.
> After stopping and removing 8+ containers, it finally stopped

That is why I have [aliases to quickly remove any stopped containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309).

Comment: yes, i tried that and did see that PR. When I first ran the start rancher server command, I didn't notice that it was being downloaded. So I may have retried that command a couple times. That must  be why the job kept on restarting even after stopping and removing containers that was started as rancher server. After stopping and removing  8+ containers, it finally stopped.

Comment: @codefire OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 12):

it keeps restarting because you're using `--restart=always` flag

Run

```
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>
```

to see if your code is encountering any errors that does not allow the container to run properly

Comment: this helped me! thanks

Answer (score 1):

These solutions are correct! But for me there was a situation when these answers did not work out. That's because I was running service in the background I did not remove it so it keeps running even you remove container it will restart it again and so on...
So answer to that specific problem is

```
docker service rm service name or id
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, but for me even using the answer von VonC the problem continues.
After researching Kubernetes was running the image again and again.

Use `kubectl get nodes` to get the nodes u have and later run:

```
kubectl drain NODE_ID --delete-emptydir-data --ignore-daemonsets
```

Comment: That should work indeed. Kubernetes was still nascent back in 2016, when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. U help me a lot! That is why i've voted for your answer! :-)

Answer (score -2):

Docker run in your locahost if you shutdown/kill docker damen then docker stop and inside in docker container delete data if you not save your data in external volume.

docker run -d  nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80  nginx