# Docker swarm: 'build' configuration in docker compose file ignored during stack deployment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

We have created a docker compose file with multiple services. The images for these services are built in runtime using 'build' configuration option. The corresponding Dockerfile(s) are given in the respective directories.

Sample docker compose file...

```
version: '3'
services:
  db2server:
    build: ./db2server
    ports:
      - "50005:50000"
    command: ["db2start"]
  appruntime:
    build: ./appruntime
    depends_on:
     - db2server
```

This docker compose file works with `docker-compose` command.

- The images are built in runtime from the Dockerfile(s) present in `db2server` & `appruntime` directories
- These images get deployed in the host machine

But when we try to deploy this in a docker swarm, the following error is thrown...

> docker stack deploy -c /home/docker/docker-compose.yml app

```
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Creating network app_default
Creating service app_db2server
failed to create service app_db2server: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided
```

Looks like the 'build' configuration option is ignored during stack deployment in docker swarm.

How can we deploy these services (with build option) defined in docker compose file in a docker swarm.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short answer is, you can not use the `build` command with `docker stack deploy`.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build):

> **Note**: The `docker stack` command `build` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file. The `docker stack` command accepts only pre-built images.

An alternative is to build the docker image before deploying the your swarm cluster.

Use the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command to create the docker image; Push the created image to a (public or private) `docker registry`; and reference it in your `docker compose` file.

Comment: I found building, pushing image is time consuming for minor development modifications, is there a less time-consuming alternative?

Comment: You can use [labels](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/#add-or-remove-label-metadata) to set a development node, you can constrain your stack to run only in that node and that way you don't have to push the image if you build it on that same node.

Answer (score 25):

If anyone is still on this you can tag the built image in compose by setting the image parameter along with the build parameter, as you can see in the build section of the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). So the file should look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db2server:
    image: <your registry here>/db2server
    build: ./db2server
    ports:
      - "50005:50000"
    command: ["db2start"]
  appruntime:
    image: <your registry here>/appruntime
    build: ./appruntime
    depends_on:
     - db2server
```

then you can do:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
docker stack deploy -c /home/docker/docker-compose.yml app
```

Comment: It would be nice if `docker stack` supported flags like `--build` which would only be available when using e.g. `--orchestrator none` or `--orchestrator singlenode`

Answer (score 11):

The compose file serves both tools: `docker-compose` cli, and `docker stack` cli. the "build" options work in `docker-compose` but are ignored by stack commands, and the "deploy" options work in stack commands but are ignored by `docker-compose`.

Swarm is not designed to build your images for you. It assumes you're images are available in a image registry. Multiple nodes in a Swarm can't share images with each other, so a registry (either remote or running on the Swarm itself) is the only way they can all ensure they can pull the same exact image.

So the typical example is to either have Docker Hub auto-build your images based on code commits, or have your CI/CD platform build the images and push to a registry. Then your `stack deploy` commands will pull the proper image from that registry.