# Docker creates dangling images when no running container exists

Tags: docker, docker-build

I try to dockerize my Java app. Whenever I build a new image, Docker adds the new image into the list without removing the old images. I don't run the images, I just build again and again. I think it should remove the old ones. Am I wrong?

Docker file

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./build/libs/admin-app-0.1.jar app.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Commands

```
sudo gradle build
sudo docker build . -t admin-app:latest
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you end with **dangling images** (images not tagged displaying `<none>` on their name) is that **you are building the same image several times successfully with the same name / tag**: `admin-app:latest`.
In this case the previous (old) image that were already built with this tag becomes a "dangling image" since the new built image has replaced it. Docker does not want to overwrite (delete) it and simply indicates that this image has no name by tagging it `<none>`.

You can also produce dangling images when the build is failing.

To get rid of dangling image you can either:

- Use a a different tag each time you perform a build to avoid images tagged with `<none>`.
- Remove them by using `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`.

Answer (score -1):

this is completly normal. docker creates in the build process containers and throw them away after build the final container. see here (http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/)

youn can easily remove them with some bash rows. see here ([How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images))

Comment: You can go ahead and remove them without any harm.

Remember Docker image is a collection of arranged layers. Whenever you recreate image with some updates, another layer gets added on top of the previously existing layers.

Refer this explaination here http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/