# How to repair docker or reinstall it?

Tags: docker

I have done this command and now docker don't work...

How can I repair (or reintall) docker properly?

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

I have try to do

```
apt-get install --reinstall docker
```

but it didn't work

this is my error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/c14f6c4750a2a3fcfa33e6f33041bf4fce087d314fb413ee3662e6e7035fea75: no such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That was seen only with older versions of docker ([issue 22343](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22343)), but also more recently with 16.04.1 LTS, Docker version 1.12.1, build

It depends on which docker you are using, and on which host OS.

If you are on Ubuntu for instance, try removing docker completely (**if you don't have any local work that you would want to keep**)

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker # This deletes all images, containers, and volumes
```

Then install the latest docker 13.1 and see if the issue persists.

Again, this is only if you are ready to start again from a clean state, reinstalling Docker entirely.
Do *not* execute `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` without considering the consequences, or in a production environment(!).

[rakeshz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242005/rakeshz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914939/6309) using an [`apt-get install --reinstall`](https://askubuntu.com/a/632092/5470) is a safer first step.

---

Note: [Crouching Kitten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630230/crouching-kitten) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264617/how-to-repair-docker-or-reinstall-it/42265926?noredirect=1#comment133529350_42265926):

> I also had to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.postinst` and add `exit 0` on the second line, otherwise the `purge` command didn't execute.

Comment: @MelissaLoos Sorry to hear that. I guess a full reinstallation is the only way?

Comment: Why would you post this? DO NOT RUN THIS COMMAND!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @RobertMcelvenny why not? Do you mean that we can reinstall or repair the docker without having to manually delete all the old files (which may size up to 50GB as in my case)? Can a repair (if possible) make the docker engine use those old files (so that right after repairing, we can just run `docker images` and see all the old images listed correctly?)

Comment: Because it will remove other required apps, dependencies... special things, not just docker.

Comment: Exactly... and it will break things.

Comment: If it broke before, why not remove the broken parts and build it again? Sure, you have to know what you are doing. @VonC put up a warning in the answer.

Comment: I also had to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.postinst` and add `exit 0` on the second line, otherwise the purge command didn't execute.

Answer (score 19):

Try this on ubuntu with docker-ce

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Docker Desktop on MacOS and couldn't update it.

It seemed corrupted.

I ended up downloading Docker Desktop and just overwrite the current app.

Comment: Their uninstall script might help too: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/

Answer (score 0):

After I do the `docker system prune` or reset to factory default on Docker Destop but still doesn't get disk space back.
The cause of this is the Temporary files that can't be deleted on Disk Cleanup and I don't know why, but I use the windows 10 and the below steps help me.

Windows search bar >> storage setting >> Configure Storage Sense or run it now >> on `Free up space now` section, press `Clean now` button

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34972045)

Answer (score 0):

First try use `docker system prune` which will clear out the following things:

- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all dangling images
- all dangling build cache

Try restarting the docker daemon. Since I am using MacOS, the docker desktop has to be restarted in my case.

If the problem persists, try: `sudo apt remove docker` and `sudo apt install docker`

Cleaning all the files related to docker can be helpful as it would clear all the files disturbing the running of docker. This can be done by deleting the `var/lib/docker` as well as any cache related to it.