# How to delete a Docker image that has no tag?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I use docker since 5months and I never got this problem. I have 2 images with the same ID so I want to delete the one who I know that it's deprecated. The thing is that it has no ID and when I try to do

```
 dk rmi -f gitlab-lab:5005/xs/mgmt-docker-gui
```

I got an error :

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: gitlab-lab:5005/xs/mgmt-docker-gui:latest
```

So how can I delete this one and not the other one who has the same ID ?

```
jerome/mgmt-docker-ui                latest              537b5ea5aa7b        4 days ago          476 MB
gitlab-lab:5005/xs/mgmt-docker-gui   <none>              537b5ea5aa7b        4 days ago          476 MB
```

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe that you are referring to image with tag `<none>`. If so, then you can delete using `dangling` switch.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

Comment: it will delete all the images that have no tags right ? Can I do that only for a specific one ?

Comment: only with `<none>` tag.

Comment: Ok perfect so !

Comment: I don't think it will free any disk space nor delete any image though, only the reference you are seeing in "docker images" will disappear.

Comment: The main benefit is readability, anything else is a plus IMHO