# How to delete all tagged docker images?

Tags: docker, delete-file, docker-image

To delete all docker containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Or this too deletes all docker containers:

```
docker ps -q -a | xargs docker rm
```

To delete images that has no tag, i.e. to delete `docker images` where the `REPOSITORY` names are `<none>` (from [How to delete a Docker image that has no tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779277/how-to-delete-a-docker-image-that-has-no-tag)):

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

But after deleting all "dangling" images and containers, when I do a `docker images`, there are still tonnes of images that I no longer use and wants to delete:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tofufu                   latest              9bcb9d31a3f8        17 hours ago        900 MB
alvations/mosesdecoder   ubuntu-basic        245c85d5fef1        5 days ago          2.22 GB
ubuntu-basic             latest              245c85d5fef1        5 days ago          2.22 GB
alvations/mosesdecoder   latest              8485b998412d        5 days ago          2.33 GB
alvations/mosesdecoder   vanilla-moses       8485b998412d        5 days ago          2.33 GB
vanilla-moses            latest              8485b998412d        5 days ago          2.33 GB
moses-ubuntu-basic       latest              18d42b9bea18        5 days ago          2.22 GB
vanilla                  latest              74f314d03c43        5 days ago          2.33 GB
moses-dev                latest              38fd8cbf31fa        6 days ago          2.33 GB
centos                   latest              02b4bf8694ab        6 days ago          192 MB
moses-prod               latest              027aa7c94428        6 days ago          1.97 GB
momo                     latest              d8a579e8996f        7 days ago          130 MB
alvations/test-push      latest              6603ab6ae8da        7 days ago          130 MB
testcommit               latest              6603ab6ae8da        7 days ago          130 MB
alvations/momo           latest              5b1d2dd9d365        10 days ago         2.34 GB
centos                   <none>              a8493f5f50ff        11 days ago         192 MB
ubuntu                   latest              0ef2e08ed3fa        7 weeks ago         130 MB
hello-world              latest              48b5124b2768        3 months ago        1.84 kB
```

**How should I delete these images with tags?**

I've tried this that deleted some images but not all:

```
$ docker images | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rmi
Untagged: tofufu:latest
Deleted: sha256:9bcb9d31a3f8dd5188e4dccc847b767b7bf3e95dcdb63b60ca3e922c54ad219c
Deleted: sha256:90e8dd5e4ee7cb533f59c5781369a9d0dba7d3b7fc4ac7009b9c47a9af37b823
Deleted: sha256:88b3d2386d46090d52754ea79105fb934a08e2635bd0c1956bb6ec08ccf4f309
Deleted: sha256:a5c70de0a061964fc7e977d634ded413e2b350b5c8aef53a1764401d479d0306
Deleted: sha256:cc8bb6e33edf9ee0a2803d9e0d8f21fecea339e4bc209873b9d734631e4a1a23
Deleted: sha256:18ba056cacab877680e69b1013fe72ae22658cfe139d8dae7e682b0a9afb2e16
Deleted: sha256:578320a8d061b2f4be68e9f196a5de55947f0de17ed2541fcc76b33d7ee0b54e
Deleted: sha256:5a14d7565600534047b8f3efa71aba5890168131ea4c167566a2e2967a16cd77
Deleted: sha256:d413f752c720c742883288b92a7ce58a30352fbb3d67eddd88e8285c07979e48
Deleted: sha256:1d34ae184a0dccbd27c0a6f17ab2cecad65570fe63746581b5dc78a61fe919d2
Deleted: sha256:938de745f481473ea60a821a0b68a64d0d89077a5772e006ad2a3507dc3a5e9a
Deleted: sha256:05b0cb9c863b2ca44587f2e93f05d146fb1140e8ca4d09d73e7b2f3f98cd87f8
Deleted: sha256:7dffcf210368d569c6fcbe6abbda280c67e76a450d041520913146170d4779c3
Deleted: sha256:976ea28e69f3603f531fde2cc5c0d5d546bcc5c33ee4ee5fa165df15b4df41b2
Deleted: sha256:830a46ec34a6e083c271ec6a8aaa7686d4b21370b9956415186c3da14150dff5
Deleted: sha256:ccc94cb5ddd49b78ab7f73295790edf8ad5e63e827adb920837f906ecd487a7f
Deleted: sha256:f1660c379516f648e601476215e7e6b58cda6ac3a253a88a5464021b039a264e
Deleted: sha256:f52a1a1b8f5a61368b52e5542b8f4ed932652ec4f2ddd206fef0f1476ad476c8
Deleted: sha256:d595e0039bce268b45e63e276baedce9ff5cbd8868a7fa93911f7bc5a8b59f2f
Deleted: sha256:77fa7cf73f827511c8bcc48ccaa7e865b7ca7e9e39807427929b47b7a0fee62e
Deleted: sha256:e5c6e2930d7fe62ebdaec0c279c8c3cd5a952bb20f4a356eb4fd1e46f8b41eb6
Deleted: sha256:b2bc1f08eae79a2ac792ba7ad0874d6f54edb40b3f603473cd37c09773db3662
Deleted: sha256:d4f0e7b222b6fb2c1945353711190b17eaf214e949f65729170a4ec2bc91d40b
Deleted: sha256:6cba8e991c5d3d0b440393cf0673d6ae17f9547c2a600d7137f0acc504e12503
Deleted: sha256:fc1f8e3f054dc387a55086a2655f7e5432fc6708178d167b5af949358f742088
Untagged: alvations/mosesdecoder:latest
Untagged: ubuntu-basic:latest
Untagged: vanilla-moses:latest
Untagged: moses-ubuntu-basic:latest
Untagged: vanilla:latest
Untagged: moses-dev:latest
Deleted: sha256:38fd8cbf31fa64dc7d54295f396e9c55c2b3f6afaea35782cb2434e12c6dc188
Deleted: sha256:f8f3c9b42d5973e86eea9fc38df68d1b9ea3c5b78cb660224b16b65f01f09259
Deleted: sha256:9c6e185bfea7c8f3efe513477ff5a640bf4746baf912e0968cd4fa247ed1ee36
Deleted: sha256:4949cd3491d0c4f15fd9f451be4d975c72f15999628ef1aac5ad7a2c79ac0220
Deleted: sha256:3c879ff1e6fecd517928e238153fd538f3095ffdba03ba5ebd43db3774b81072
Deleted: sha256:562c43ae4cd4b2b6443928eb07852a424f77cf03fddd2b013d62bcc5897ada4f
Deleted: sha256:eec669470f6f4c86b23b2fac7eb72351f978e9725bd5d95d097e7b7b38e57a00
Deleted: sha256:86490b59f297643a44e5cd9cc1501ef9d31816934bce2e70b514c7b034770255
Deleted: sha256:9e7a1d7738a7e76f013eef84c5e0e8172f3058ed6c8bac4a9e052af85c3628ed
Deleted: sha256:a889879d1d7f4960fa28322fd5f4e0ff4df3c3b1d6bfe734d40f1f9681b289ad
Deleted: sha256:a2b809e55ceda9c7aaac5e05a1793097bd3b06e97cbf267a4455600727937afe
Deleted: sha256:8c0c8b490229c0e1f7ef7bf0c79929e22070610c29a2fe00f2fcc7567d53299d
Deleted: sha256:fb37064456be8fa97f4734ac4cf69dba702d05f49ea983066e86b684effb0d48
Deleted: sha256:8ffe7397a563ec16d3acc9d8be93ea49045e8e29d397db451b1d47a345924683
Deleted: sha256:3801122861128e58dfeaef7a69b0210d9cfe9d99c74c7d7782a884685fba7925
Deleted: sha256:d30634d628a8be192e583de72c5522c2ad0067ec200d15b8e15cb7c64b7f91e5
Deleted: sha256:2afb307dd142c44084869d5a7db6e6d8a4726a4aa73fbf4ee288935a6724ad76
Deleted: sha256:e4047ac7a68e429c5e253e0fb4de0780aaa72e5541fd17c660ff1c239465144f
Deleted: sha256:33ebce86e8b5659201c38a6972812d1f23049cc483dbd032b928edffd229a08b
Deleted: sha256:ecb7f12016f48ce67286409332c385db402ef8d372d09cfe49242fd54f6514c5
Deleted: sha256:dab6cd72dc4756cbc667f5fa270c82606367047d12f716660a6f9585b4e0bb9d
Deleted: sha256:9e98d039688a393d6610620ddbd4be7d1ee96cb59de11d1ea876e4cad50136be
Deleted: sha256:c715dbbe253d0e39e3f1005ff5de408447f7092e4d9b385ac7ed6bb2fc5dc4c0
Deleted: sha256:596888ac152c74c5bfd81f6c8a3b37f61ccc12df24245b2e9317131d1ca06fe4
Deleted: sha256:cb3af1db13822ffaa297f523cd25b9e4bfe8a57c0c68da924ebfcaf473c4aafd
Deleted: sha256:1dbc25d32dd3ea7082ee5b98124c796c2473b45848273bcb2660ece700723a72
Deleted: sha256:e570dd4ba591d2ca8cf5705dd0a81d7d78f3a5d6105cf9f8fa1a7b4512c81b95
Deleted: sha256:97d71168b2fecb6c132ca988da65545489b4f770e8e90650d9e3ba5650198d01
Deleted: sha256:bd956e19ab0ca1b2de7b79bd96b070de2fb178122c369f2b98b5b5be3d62876b
Deleted: sha256:d3c9b24b2313946fd7ba9a77e3f04d2a2419b0118ed0a35816d67227dea83be0
Deleted: sha256:0403dfd55883739da245e7e1fb96a218c10d08bded36afd89615f0fb077a9e2b
Deleted: sha256:2471e422e85622fc0ab4ed61abc7acb6275e421b583fc4d1b5b0b7687388a3eb
Deleted: sha256:771b0874c32f7af19b5d88c03ecd6bc38b7279247e5bfee948fd253fdef95eeb
Deleted: sha256:d56cbd9f38ef868026eab8c31f3490b98a3f02cd97d81acc6a36edf5c7c23681
Deleted: sha256:27f2ad40e4aeeb30ce26577f900b83d68a40bf90967bd4cad8c47c56db5ce776
Deleted: sha256:1b32b4aeba0dc2f687050a05c6436a106e846237eeda95f61f30f1c6c067111b
Deleted: sha256:83cc6bea0fcd5c50a14a1b4fc820339336e00345f4c9407715cbd7f1c3588a98
Deleted: sha256:95afa22d187ece76679aac10f4e4703cd281cc89f7ecb5d70450a6af73d9d4d6
Deleted: sha256:600ac47b014e18eeacb0471c161f263d9de17e68479967eb80c952ef85079818
Deleted: sha256:24d5abe9c058ebd8a111d9bd586c2f4c73fe3403862265c87773c8c53438e035
Deleted: sha256:f32f20d7a04467e8b1fa67cd48b8b39e0f0edc3abe852fd3224be5d0fb97ac06
Deleted: sha256:fb40c02566f07a569bad91b9f953dff8515b39747af3d524b3fcae5074797247
Deleted: sha256:268e3b9670f6b2e08096c0cff70ae6ceea5194e69819fbff55c0d558adc5b2db
Deleted: sha256:efda42d783b23d819f6bff07087406d31a6138718ba7c15a2ed75727eb9fd1cd
Deleted: sha256:c8b6bdbd2b39ef43f9c38d3b050adf20b4354f81840f771e8eb63c303cd6ba43
Deleted: sha256:6a538d87a0feed82b402ea5abfed350683718042e6ad9c3a241e614cc7cfcd00
Deleted: sha256:cc09394a8e3aba48a447262df3426a0a9b4093398f3a6321ffb9579235e1e072
Deleted: sha256:ba13c7b3b0c9e6f13934c9478fd267769bf15838c2684c8878e22174664b288c
Deleted: sha256:f5a38d6254ccc2d36cf58fd1beac4559c8cceac1e63e557bc77df5c77b691d20
Untagged: centos:latest
Deleted: sha256:02b4bf8694abc8ca6037d0fa73e8a8302202da6764bb0f509290eed9d353e525
Deleted: sha256:70cf4c58be700de35201ce00855837447a01e2bb5de8222745b58dcc48dd3766
Untagged: moses-prod:latest
Deleted: sha256:027aa7c9442849faa196598d5e65d2107de1d90dce2ef68fdabeaf0af25aa4fe
Deleted: sha256:bd016748fcb4dae9edbcd847b5fcb85ae6d02d72f4d771793ad38d2a8806497d
Deleted: sha256:8df46ea1f4a3812fbad858b87a222a832e9a87d45d5c931a8419f35ae2d3a60d
Deleted: sha256:d6fcf0a5fd75ef97f9c2675086c1cf38033054d75461f86d137f547f169fd04e
Deleted: sha256:b31ce69374b95d0e995d5576224178b6d9ecf376867a0f32f1090039036102d6
Deleted: sha256:b9547bdbb6818f1967d3a77b131550531f2ca5c6a837b77bddb2149da48af535
Deleted: sha256:3b02ca88cb00dd6ea67a394f8e076c53b94c4ca714f257b826d59471a06c30ca
Deleted: sha256:8ef6fc56b852499af6552b898e2ce3a67bb672a8f475d8196e4dd6476ffcd1f1
Deleted: sha256:4f458c85752ebd3aab23041d773d8c85193923c8eb2433e0336a71a4ce045c85
Deleted: sha256:8703e703782c7207a1d62ce87ad5d1a2412ad36fe56120a5a69297d10d024866
Deleted: sha256:069c2135ec9514fcd89042a5d11b3c113116daf9528d6f43c5022b48b341e467
Deleted: sha256:3f38984d40235e860610f2b71257a3045d9b1a4d9bdcd3f913cec18031fec1e4
Deleted: sha256:9983d5123bf22e0d41d8782c51a7188e852ebc9bb020f188bf53bd693d5ea1bb
Deleted: sha256:3615a9e77a1e301610eda7402e5beb20ae618395274e9bd3715a40ee047dbfc2
Deleted: sha256:eced4f5f7109d5c49e9da1d18db868161a39d8f3fbc6e06fd6411d7a968f70ef
Deleted: sha256:a580ddf48a9fdbd0a4a4b7ed4a30f2b19000208a8bed2aabf37898498dd765d6
Deleted: sha256:83fd0c744ad17d2bb6c3c7eda91af9016494bca69aa60c26fe06af3419ace337
Deleted: sha256:245fc23983ed453ddb5ba2f9fb2b5c56aa75bf4dcacd3b1b445d8ba2bb95fc0c
Deleted: sha256:2990156a3b79834a560a6982c6174476f5f58aad5c73625ea393edcfc15c48ab
Deleted: sha256:54718a75ee9a21fa7791a85a7ddfca0f828529474f6b90e5693f2ab995c82797
Deleted: sha256:348b0966a0a661ae04b7ed0b25c41217b31abe6c35ddf76ea7b3de339f53c02d
Untagged: momo:latest
Deleted: sha256:d8a579e8996fd233e1de06a46d170fcc2328a7614401982cf30f686c429a2626
Untagged: testcommit:latest
Untagged: alvations/test-push:latest
Untagged: alvations/test-push@sha256:ade6cb206c7284dc3076b6e828bde8a4d6ea4eca72e62146959f4c9a418722ca
Deleted: sha256:6603ab6ae8dad447e3625251de9aec16be41d5170ed51a06381ae727f1cd9365
Deleted: sha256:c3b3293705887ea171f2fd98fabacc80cc991f32116fb14628f20acecc9048c7
Untagged: alvations/momo:latest
Untagged: alvations/momo@sha256:fa5ab1ab7e37bc8420a9a55457f9b4a4a0acc5fc386c3081bbbc7aecf985ed81
Deleted: sha256:5b1d2dd9d365373aed51cd1577f42f1e5144696f86d8c8f364f2257660b84f14
Deleted: sha256:37ad929ea41f2c5a9b6eefbe47d090e905261b343e2af1112232f2dda6ac3d2b
Deleted: sha256:9bddfef9c5df0d0cd44810df4394eaff62c26d3b0884a57b14becd2ab532e330
Deleted: sha256:55ab30010b88042c5cab93cbcc5996143e355094edcc1f77e3b68976d94ea822
Deleted: sha256:860f46042c398843312fbbe4c8c6ac1604a8568809a3f7898ed0f14def9b1d91
Deleted: sha256:a3970d065af740285123c7c622c20a6835cb9103b2dc7c1a60f92b918b1c5b46
Deleted: sha256:c2ecb3e3f6a7fbaa45e057835b472eb23efd9deb39f9969b316dea7f9ea48c40
Deleted: sha256:7ef9ab15757c4c1c083e0e19c34fc2d282663f4fe21d7cc9869e7cc6e319c11f
Deleted: sha256:35f689eb55f0063cdc7633cef01d726ab0872944ca376690aa98e8c00245d9e1
Deleted: sha256:b10a4b3e99c92b5f66d0fd6b5912d91a12db68d12f6a8bb8c0e82ca4ee821cb1
Deleted: sha256:b6ea453841593c7aaf71421cbed5b1b4b33cae59aa24ab63568e2f4e9311aa43
Deleted: sha256:089e95ba494a7c969c5fb614ec1d67176ce2c3eafdc5002b44c5ef96bee79e52
Deleted: sha256:3f8e545359f3d434736c01a1abe99faeac3540cde292510c5eb93856ea16c817
Deleted: sha256:d37aa26d450c8959f9e9bd892380b6fadb25cc322617c0fc2be2d7d6be4db264
Deleted: sha256:24c84508de68962b67d6d61f8536196489f4610a0ec463b7ded84e6fb49c9f44
Deleted: sha256:fcbbf678c01a10e74d9bcd4a25b092b8c214289905dd4ac01ec13ac1a353428b
Deleted: sha256:a4969ddee8cca46c93187575903698b7304bb9521ead00a4e628d5b7c7258725
Deleted: sha256:489e70f676802c297ea84ce110d49550f4a9c7eb1a4c88e17688ddfbfb9296eb
Deleted: sha256:f3f1dd55a36aa8ac90b4eeb8deab030c535cfecb99823eb72743e2f82df4aafc
Deleted: sha256:32e872e90fea4632f6798763bb94f82d1e7a62af2fb045ac2a2e5f1e682df14d
Deleted: sha256:d9395a16b681404e9ddb5d7426e275c22e9b8b68be2128665bc049d6669eede7
Deleted: sha256:0d116f40d41c7f6ee1b0dde910851f15605517459aee9254fdf9d01d985cc898
Deleted: sha256:8c28deb7d823792557a32304b2f1574a8a5908ebc9a9f726009ab70bf6f4293f
Deleted: sha256:ae21f2b2bee53ba8592de77c069259388d2c4efb9a9395922bf2711e30503701
Deleted: sha256:8a64d075aa63a8aff244f5f6ecbccc575c831325d60d4617ded9ec4861e2fccf
Deleted: sha256:00ba231abd4ba371ca93fd8e69e770a14f99b46fbc6a42dbe8a4aa8ce067b7cc
Untagged: ubuntu:latest
Untagged: ubuntu@sha256:dd7808d8792c9841d0b460122f1acf0a2dd1f56404f8d1e56298048885e45535
Untagged: hello-world:latest
Untagged: hello-world@sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
Deleted: sha256:48b5124b2768d2b917edcb640435044a97967015485e812545546cbed5cf0233
Deleted: sha256:98c944e98de8d35097100ff70a31083ec57704be0991a92c51700465e4544d08
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: No such image: alvations/mosesdecoder:latest
Error response from daemon: No such image: alvations/mosesdecoder:latest
Error response from daemon: No such image: centos:latest
```

And after the previous `docker rmi`, the `docker images` still shows 3 images:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alvations/mosesdecoder   ubuntu-basic        245c85d5fef1        5 days ago          2.22 GB
alvations/mosesdecoder   vanilla-moses       8485b998412d        5 days ago          2.33 GB
centos                   <none>              a8493f5f50ff        11 days ago         192 MB
```

**How to delete tagged docker images?**

---

## EDITED

I've also tried:

```
$ docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

And it deleted the images, but is that the canonical way to remove the tagged images?

Comment: Have you looked at the prune commands, like `docker image prune`?

Comment: @DanLowe prune only deletes dangling images right?

Comment: That is true. I'll point out that the remaining images are those which were duplicates (> 1 instance in your list). Perhaps you'd have better luck with `awk '{print $1 ":" $2}'` but it would need some tweaking to deal with `<none>` tags.

Comment: `docker prune image -a` removes all images. Since you're asking how to remove untagged images, doesn't this `$ docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi` remove every images?

Answer (score 9):

Do you want to delete all dangling images??

```
docker image prune
```

to delete images without at least one container associated to it

```
docker image prune -a
```

Answer (score 4):

To delete tagged docker images (and delete the tags) a list can be produced with the following command. It facilitates the go template format.

```
# docker images --format '{{.Repository}}{{if eq .Tag "<none>"}}:latest{{else}}:{{.Tag}}{{end}}' | xargs docker rmi
```

To delete any leftovers issue another:

```
# docker images -q | xargs docker rmi
```

Any active image bound to a countainer will be retained.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all tags for a specific docker image you can use this command:

```bash
docker rmi $(docker images -q <image_name>)
```