# Cannot run or delete images or container (fail overlay2)

Tags: docker

When I want to delete all my container I see that error

Command:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

the error is:

```
Error response from daemon: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem for 4bf2fc329d2fab3c055dd136a740c5ee2000e35e26fea6a38c94801fd8dfb109: remove /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7991f36adaa25d4046ef6106c3da8bbbb1f3ce7478b07a30021669a7783b4b6c/diff/root/.ipython: read-only file system
```

Also I have tried

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

But the result was the same

Also I have tried to delete that image:

```
docker rmi -f <images_id>
```

And the result was the same.

How can I delete the container?

Comment: I have fixed it, I restart my laptop and now everything is good. But what happened before I do not know

Comment: I hit the same error, in my case while running docker inside a Linux VM, and discovered afterwards that the VM's root filesystem mount had been remounted read-only -- so I could not even write to a file *on the host!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check what your filesystem is: [moby/moby issue 9939](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9939#issuecomment-374932930) reports:

> Does the overlay2 driver work on a btrfs file system?
>   [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/) says only ext4 and xfs are supported.

See also if [`docker system prune`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309) can help.

Restarting the computer, to clear any locked file can help too.

Comment: My file system is ext4

Comment: @AndreyBerenda OK, so probably some file locked by a process then.

Comment: Rebooting worked fine for me! Thanks