# Deletion of all my local docker images and containers is not working

Tags: docker

I am unable to delete all my local docker containers or images and below is the error I am getting. Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

docker rmi $(docker ps -a -q)

unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a

See 'docker rmi --help'.<\br>

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker ps` is pulling a list of the containers you have, not the images, and `rmi` is used for removing images, not containers.

Use `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

If you want to clean up your docker space, check out the `prune` command, for example:

`docker system prune`

`docker image prune`

`docker container prune`

Comment: I am trying to delete all my containers first and that's where I am using 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'  and once done with it I thought of using 'docker rmi $(docker images -q)' to delete the images. But the problem I am facing in deleting all the containers first. Logically it should work and the command is pretty straightforward.

Comment: So i deleted all my containers manually one by one and used below command to delete all the images 'docker rmi $(docker images -q)' . It worked

Comment: Please read my answer correctly, you are using the command `docker rmi` (which removes *images*) in conjunction with `docker ps` which lists *containers*. If you want to remove *containers* then use: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: You are right. Ooops I overlooked the problem. Thanks