# How can I delete docker images older than X and not in use

Tags: docker

I'm running out of disk space on a server and `docker images` shows some containers from 6 months ago but as old as 2 years ago.  I'd like to remove all the ones older than 8 months.  What magic can I add to `docker rmi $(MAGIC)` that'll accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `docker images prune`  which will delete all images that are not being used by any container, combining it with `filter` makes you able to delete images with certain conditions, according to [this docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images) where it says:

You can limit which images are pruned using filtering expressions with the `--filter` flag. For example, to only consider images created more than 24 hours ago

```
$ docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h"
```

In case you need to delete images older than 8 months the command would be:

```
$ docker image prune -a --filter "until=5840h"
```

**Update:**
A more flexible version of the command above in case you need to change the value of `until`. Given that `1` month equals to `730` hour approximately and we need to delete images older than `8` months then we can use the command as the following and let the bash do the math:

```
$ docker image prune -a --filter "until=$((8 * 730))h"
```