# What does `docker system prune -a` actually do?

Tags: docker

My empty space before running `docker system prune -a` was 900 MB and running it gives me **65 GB free space** although the command report that it cleaned **only 14.5 GB**

Is the report is just wrong on am I missing something here?

The docs is not telling something new and it would be normal if it clears only 14.5 GB and this only gives me one answer that I'm doing it in a wrong way. Any thoughts here?

Comment: I've added an answer here that provides a detailed explanation of what `docker system prune -a` is doing - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536542/1549918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove following content form your host machine where docker is running

```
    - all stopped containers
    - all networks not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
    - all build cache
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer , but the I'm looking for why it report for only 14.5 GB but actually it frees around 64 GB

Comment: And maybe it is something under the hood in docker itself and maybe there is no right answer for my question at all 

Comment: @MohamedAbuGalala when you run above command how much Total reclaimed space was there?

Comment: around 64 GB

#####